# Android view is missing after cloning Github repository

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

I have projects on my Github account that I need to have on my local machine yet every time I clone an Android project, the clone completes successfully but the project doesn't have the android view in the upper-left dropdown, and neither can it run on any device.

I also get this notification below

```
Unable to get Gradle wrapper properties from:
/home/.../gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
Would you like to recreate the wrapper using the latest supported Gradle version?
Click 'OK' to recreate files, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of a local Gradle distribution.
```

Whether I click 'OK', 'Cancel' or ignore the prompt, in the end, I still have an app that can't run.

I've tried changing the minimum SDK Version and importing the project instead of cloning but it wouldn't solve the problem. Is anyone willing to help?

[image: Check out the screenshot here]

Comment: Please, can you provide the link to your repo to check out how are you storing it in github?

Comment: @BogdanAndroid, https://github.com/TonaDaphin/my-restaurants. That is the repo

Comment: I can see in your repo that your project is missing some files like:
my-restaurants>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties
That files shouldn't be obligatory but I think is causing your error.
Also I see you miss the my-restaurants>settings.gradle file.
I suggest you to create an empty project, check the files it creates and copy & paste the missing files into the root of your project.

Comment: Thanks, I created the settings.gradle file, added the include and rootProject.name lines and it worked. I still can't figure out why the files are missing from all cloned projects though.

Comment: Nice! Glad to know we solved the problem! About that files, I just can imagine that you didn't track them when you did the initial commit, just take care next time you start the project and make the initial commit to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before
I updated my Android studio version, otherwise try to update SDK of the android studio.